# Is it possible to enable/disable cheats on an existing Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can you enable or disable cheats after you make an offline server?

My brother did something in the settings menu but I can't find it.

Answer (score 19):

## On a multiplayer server:

On a multiplayer server, players can use cheats if they are a server operator.

To make a player an operator:

1. Type `/op <username>` in the console, of course replacing the appropriate part with the player's username.
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit. Done.

To revoke operator status:

1. Type `/deop <username>`.
2. Submit. Done.

## On a singleplayer world:

On a singleplayer world, cheat settings are deliberately not available on purpose. This is to discourage, well, cheating. However, there are workarounds to enable cheats on a singleplayer world:

### Using the built-in LAN server:

When you open a world to the built-in LAN server, you get a chance to configure settings such as cheats. Settings configured in this menu will only apply until the world is closed.

1. Pause the game.
2. Click <kbd>Open to LAN</kbd>.
3. Select your desired setting for cheats from the buttons.
4. Open the server.

**Note:** If your world has cheats disabled, enabling cheats here *will* enable cheats for you. However, disabling cheats on a cheats-enabled world only affects other players who join, not you.

### Manually editing your save file

You need an NBT editor. Need one? Try [NBT Studio](https://github.com/tryashtar/nbt-studio).

1. Close your world.
2. Using NBTEdit, open your save file (`%APPDATA%/.minecraft/saves/<worldName>/level.dat`)
3. Change the NBT tag `AllowCommands`. Use `1` to enable or `0` to disable cheats.
4. Save, then reopen the world.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Shout out to all the people telling me this wasn't possibly. Let alone that simple!

Comment: Then what is `op-permission-level` in `server.properties` and how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply deop yourself. `/deop {PlayerName}` and boom, no more commands like /gamemode 1

Comment: Player name as in the what you called the server or your profile?

Comment: Your profile name, as in the name in the launcher (Hello, TheEnderCrafter9) as an example

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode creative`

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to make it so that no one can use any commands, then...

1. Make the map open to **LAN**
2. Turn cheats to "**Off**"
3. End the LAN server and you won't be able to use cheats.

This works the other way around if you wish to turn the cheats back on.

Answer (score 0):

For Permanent allow command without LAN MODE use this:

[NTB EXPLORER](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/releases) for change config on the world.

Next, open the program and go to

```
C:\Users\ *"MY USER"* \AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves
```

Select the world folder and in the file "**level.dat**" search "**AllowCommands**" and change 0 to 1 (0 = false, 1 = true)

Make this change with minecraft close.