# How to activate Roughly Enough Items cheating?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How in the world can you activate cheat mode in the Roughly Enough Items mod? I tried to but it says no permission to do so. Can someone pls help me with this. I am using fabric modloader Thanks!

Comment: To the close voters, this isn't technical support: this is just normal support because Minecraft isn't crashing or erroring out. This is just normal mod support and is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hypothesis that I have tested, and can confirm firsthand that your world unfortunately does not have enable cheats turned on! "Roughly Enough items" respects the cheats option in the world settings, presumably because in the background it is merely executing commands on your behalf. When you click an item, it is likely just executing a give command. Without permission, it may not be able to do this.

To turn singleplayer cheats on, here is an excerpt from:
[How to turn cheats on or off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277542/how-to-turn-cheats-on-or-off)
with credit to user aytimothy and users who revised the question.

## On a singleplayer world:

#### To turn on cheats:

**Using the built-in LAN server:**

1. Pause the game.
2. Click on `Open to LAN`.
3. In the options, change <kbd>Allow Cheats: false</kbd> to true (click on it).
4. Open the server.

**Changing your save file:**

1. Close your world.
2. Using NBTEdit, open your save file (`%AppData%/.minecraft/saves/<World Name>/save.dat`)
3. Change the NBT node `AllowCommands` from `0` to `1`.
4. Save and reopen the world.

Comment: Then how do you use command method? Because i want to edit the nbt. So if i click on a item, it will have Unbreakable tag. I search the whole night just for this and not getting an answer. Otherwise, is there a command that modify mainhand item to have Unbreakable tag?